# Can any one explain Netezza Disadvantages?

Tags: olap, teradata, netezza, vertica, greenplum

While i am going through the Netezza OLAP appliance , i could see Netezza dynamic scaling is not possible,

**can anyone please explain this ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To start with :****netezza :**

- not a columnar db
- mix of olap & oltp
- not mmp db
- uses lots of memory for DB strucutres
- downtime for maintainance

**The good stuff**
 - excelent integration with SAS,R,SPSS
 - fast analitics
 - simple to install and maintain
 - excelent integration with BI/ETL tools
 - row-lelev security support
 - uses pk at load time

**The bad stuff**
 - is row store (means is I/O bound)
 - poor enterprise fit (PostgreSQL foundation)
 - memory hog when more then 10 concurent queries
 - upgrade is a big problem ,"fork lift" required.
 - no internal storage
 - data load is limited ot 4 concurent streams
 - poor export perf becouse of the single head node
 - space reclaim lock the table in full lock

Go for HP Vertica

Hope this helps !!